# WSUS Sync Failure in the middle of synchronization

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, wsus

The WSUS sync with upstream server starts fine and all of a sudden fails in the middle of synchronization:

```
Sync failed:  IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: 
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. --->
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:An existing connection was forcibly closed 
by the remote host  at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, int32 offset,int32 size)
at Microsoft.UpdateServices.ServerSync.ServerSyncCompressionProxy.GetWebResponse(WebRequest webRequest) 
at System.WebServices.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) 
at Microsoft.UpdateServices.ServerSync.Webservices.ServerSync.ServerSyncProxy.GetUpdateData(Cookie cookie, UpdateIdentity[] updateIds) 
at Microsoft.UpdateServices.ServerSync.CatlogSyncAgentCore.WebserviceGetUpdateData(UpdateIdentity[] updateIds, List`1 allMetadata,List`1 allFleUrls,Boolean isForConfig) 
at Microsoft.UpdateServices.ServerSync.CatlogSyncAgentCore.GetUpdateDatainChunksAndlmport(List`1 allMetadata,List`1 allFleUrls,Boolean isForConfigData)
at Microsoft.UpdateServices.ServerSync.CatlogSyncAgentCore.ExecuteSyncProtocol(boolean allowRedirect))
```

Comment: Please update your question with more information about your environment.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same exact problem with one WSUS on 2012 R2. For some unknown reason, disabling and enabling "TCP Receive Window Auto-Tuning Level" knob made the problem go away.

I have done this:

```
netsh interface tcp show global
Querying active state...

TCP Global Parameters
----------------------------------------------
Receive-Side Scaling State          : enabled
Chimney Offload State               : disabled
NetDMA State                        : disabled
Direct Cache Access (DCA)           : disabled
**Receive Window Auto-Tuning Level    : normal**
Add-On Congestion Control Provider  : none
ECN Capability                      : enabled
RFC 1323 Timestamps                 : disabled
Initial RTO                         : 3000
Receive Segment Coalescing State    : enabled
Non Sack Rtt Resiliency             : disabled
Max SYN Retransmissions             : 2

netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled
Ok.
```

Do the WSUS sync

```
netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=normal
Ok.
```

Do the WSUS sync again